# Compare the dictionary order topology and product topology on RxR.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I am not able to start this problem although I know the definitions for the basis of  dictionary order topology on RxR and product topology on RxR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: Show first that if $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $\Bbb R$, then $U\times V$ is open in the dictionary order topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$; this is completely straightforward if you understand the definition of the dictionary order topology. Then use the fact that sets of the form $U\times V$ with $U$ and $V$ open in $\Bbb R$ are a base for the product topology to show that every set that is open in the product topology is also open in the dictionary order topology. Finally, find a set that is open in the dictionary order topology but not in the product topology; there are very simple examples.

Comment: Is this (  (1/2x1/2), (1x1) ) example valid ? Because the union of rectangles won't include all the points of above interval. Even if this is right I think it is bit shaky and informal. If correct how do I say it more formally ?

Comment: @Siddharth: Yes, that interval in the order topology is not open in the usual topology. For example, the point $1\times 0$ is in it, but the interval doesn't contain any ordinary open nbhd of that point. There are much simpler examples, though; you could use the $y$-axis, for instance. It is clearly open in the order topology, and it clearly doesn't contain any non-empty open set in the usual topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott in above comment you said " any ordinary open nbhd of that point". Should I think of an open disc centered at (0,1) and it is not contained in  ((1/2x1/2),(1,1)) and that's why this set is not open in product topology?

Comment: @caleb: Yes, that will work; the open disks are one base for the product topology, though not the most natural one.